# Generate ArcGIS spatial bookmarks from feature envelope

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, bookmarks

Curious if anyone has some code that would rip through a feature class and generate a spatial bookmark for each feature's envelope. There can be a field in the feature class to hold the bookmark's name.

Comment: I've changed my mind because while it is easy to iterate through the extents of features in a feature class and to read the field value you are interested in, there seems to be no DataFrame or MapDocument property to create a bookmark.  That could be a good ArcGIS Idea for ArcGIS Professional.

Comment: Can you edit your question to update it with the code language that you are looking for, please?

Comment: This can be done with the python Comtypes library.  Some cool opportunities available.  See presentation by Mark Cederholm http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis10/upload/python/arcmap_and_python.pdf and http://www.pierssen.com/arcgis/upload/misc/python_arcobjects.pdf

Comment: @Jeff Garland, Is using comtypes an option for you?

Answer (score -2):

I suppose I would break this down into two discinct parts.  I have a polygon FC that stores multi-part features with a unique name.  First step would be to generate a polygon FC that represents the envelope that encompasses each features.  (You can do this with AGS Adv.  I'n not licesned at that level.) This would representa a prospect area. 
Second step would be to rip through that FC and generate bookmarks that correspond with each envelope feature.  I want to provide the user with two means of zooming to a propesct area: 1) query the prospect, and 2) choose a bookmark.

Comment: To your original questions. A python script bundled as GP tool.

Comment: For the tone of this "answer", it sounds like it may have been provided by @Jeff Garland?  If so, it should really be an "update" to the question, not an answer.

Comment: It looks like you have created two accounts.  Please merge them ASAP using [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That way this "answer" can become an edit to your question.